# Ubuntu core - Difference between snap set and direct change in filesystem

Tags: snap, configuration, ubuntu-core

Ubuntu core has some [configuration options](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/ubuntu-core-configuration). I do not understand what is the difference when I configure system through this "snap set" or directly in /etc folder? (e.g. netplan can be configured through "snap set" or directly in the /etc/netplan folder). Are both ways to change/configure it the same? Or some of them is somehow less persistent than the other? Or better than the other? I am new to ubuntu core and I can't find any info about this.

Thank you.